# Getting javascript function to carry over pages via linked html-page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a header in a separate header.html file, in which I have a button that changes the contrast of the page with accompanying javascript to change some class names so the header.css file can add features. I plan on having it influence the css in these pages as well. I link the header.html via a jquery function as such:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#header").load("header.html");
    })
</script>
```

My problem is that the button seems to stop functioning once I click the button on the other page, such as the home page.

The function of the button is written this way in the header.html:

```
<script src="function.js"></script>
...
...
...
<button type="button" class="contrastBtn" id="myContrastBtn" onclick="contrast()">Change Contrast</button>
```

Is there a way to keep the functionality across pages, specifically to change the css of these pages individual .css files or do I need to reproduce the button for each and every page?

Comment: Please post relevant code. Where is `contrast()` and how does it look. Why not use localStorage? And yes, you would have to show a button on each page you wanted to change the contrast with.

Comment: You could use the onpageload event if you want the html to load when the page loads.